# How to show a demo of a WP app on another PC?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, installation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have a small WP app and I need to show a (interactive) demo of it and show its features, to another person who doesn't have any WP-related software installed on his PC.

Is there a super lite version of the WP emulator that the other person can download?

Also, how can I create an installation file of the WP app so that it would be easy for him to install & run ?

Surely he won't need to install the whole SDK, including Visual Studio, right?

Answer (score 1):

To run the emulator you'll need to install the full SDK (http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) but note that this doesn't require an existing version of Visual Studio.
There is no stand alone installer for just the emulator.

Apps are compiled into XAP files (similar to APK) and the `Application Deployment` application (installed as part of the SDK) will allow this to be loaded into the emulator.  This tool can also be used to load the app into attached, developer unlocked, devices.

In terms of demonstrating an app to someone not familiar with Windows Phone, I've found that getting them to experience it on an emulator is often a sub-par experience and doesn't create the best experience. It's far better to get people to experience applications on actual devices. Alternatively, if it's very early in the application's development it's often better just to capture a video of the application running (from the emulator if fine and normally easier).

Comment: How do I get to create the XAP file, and if I send it to the other person, how would he install & run it on the emulator (he doesn't have a device yet) ?

Comment: When you build the project the XAP file will be built. This is what is installed on devices/emulators when you run from within VS. look in [project folder]/bin/debug. install it with the application called `Application Deployment`. Check the installed apps on your PC. You give it the XAP path and the emulator or device you wish to install on.

Answer (score 0):

He would need to install VS Express with all the requirements that needs (Win8, CPU support for Client Hyper-V).

Emulator works pretty well over Remote Desktop and other remote viewing tech such as Skype, so that's another option.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact links? Also, can I send him a single file that doesn't require him to open a solution and start to build ? something like APK file on android (or single EXE file on windows) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i've found the needed steps:

1. send the XAP file from "Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AppName\Bin\Release\" where "AppName" is the name of the app.
2. download and install the [sdk](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk) . not sure if Visual studio is needed.
3. run "XapDeploy.exe" tool which will allow to run the emulator and install the XAP file into it.
   The file is somewhere similar to :
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment
4. run the app from within the emulator.